# U16.04- DNS messed up, must edit /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf after booting

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, dns, resolvconf

Somehow I've clobbered my whole DNS system in 16.04.
I now must edit `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` to add a name server such as
nameserver `8.8.8.8` or similar.
Of course, this always disappears after a reboot.
(And, yes, I KNOW I'm not supposed to hack it this way!)

NOTE: I'm accessing the router through wifi, not Ethernet.

I have tried editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` - it currently shows

```
[main]  
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono  
dns=dnsmasq  
[ifupdown]  
managed=false
```

I've tried commenting out the `dns=` line but still the problem persists.
I have tried edited the ipv4 params in the wifi-settings, attempting to use either static or auto - but it's still no go after a reboot.

Currently my `/etc/network/interfaces shows

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  
address 192.168.200.44  
netmask 255.255.255.0   
gateway 192.168.200.1  
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4**
```

I added the IP-data lines there as a last resort. Presumably, they mean nothing if I have used  "loopback" instead of "static", right?

Ideally, I'd like to use DHCP instead of a static, but use my own nameservers such as google or OpenDNS.
So where can I look to see what the problem with BOTH my DNS and Static is?

Answer (score 1):

First, as it is badly malformed, return your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to default:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

Second, you can easily set your own DNS nameservers in Network Manager like this: https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3898/14334590042_3c72168038_o.jpg

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: @chiliSSS - As per my OP,    **_I have tried edited the ipv4 params in the wifi-settings, attempting to use either static or auto _ **           
  And, yes, I have already tried the **Automatic (DHCP) addresses only**  option as well, using both Google's AND OpenDNS's nameservers.       
    
Seems to have no effect.

Comment: May we please see an entire diagnostic? http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I'm sorry, but you will have to specify what "an entire diagnostic" is.  General terms don't help.

Comment: If you click the link I gave, it explains how to download and run a script that gathers all the information in one report that you can post in your question or else here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com It's all explained in the link.

Comment: OKAY, Chilidawg...  I finally got around to this after a month or so.  Hope you can make some sense of it. NEAT SCRIPT! Up to now, I've been busy re-creating the run - resolv conf with a simple resolv.conf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf  from my home dir every time I boot into Linux.        So finally I've gotten around to running yr script.      It is at  -        http://paste.ubuntu.com/23755617/          The gen mentioned it was bigger than  xxxK, USE THE GZIP,  But I think it is all there.  Happy New Year!

Comment: May we have the link to the result, please?

Comment: Damn! yr too fast for me!

Comment: How do I create a newline in "comment"?  shift-enter doesn't do it.

Comment: May I assume the entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` is the one you manually entered? If you reboot and do not make the entry, you can't resolve IP addresses? Is the file a symbolic link? `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`Is Network Manager set to DHCP or static or addresses only with DNS specified?

Comment: The entry in /etc/resolv.conf  I have not touched (AFAIK).  Perhaps I DID enter it there back in December- not sure. If I reboot, the entry in /run/resolv.conf is missing.  So I simply copy a resolv.conf from my home dir to it.  Contents = nameserver 8.8.4.4      .... running ls -al yields lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb 20  2015 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf          Oh yeah- again- How do I create a newline here? (easier to read)